# Intersection in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with the following format.

```
ID | Value
1  | AAA
2  | XXX
3  | BBB
1  | XXX
2  | CCC
3  | DDD
1  | YYY
2  | DDD
3  | XXX
```

How can I find the intersection within IDs?

```
1 -> AAA,XXX,YYY
2 -> XXX,CCC,DDD
3 -> BBB,DDD,XXX
```

`Expected result: XXX`

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouping by `Value` and checking which groups have all values present

```
val cnt = df.select($"ID").distinct().count()
df.groupBy($"Value")
  .agg(countDistinct("ID") as "cnt")
  .filter($"cnt" === cnt)
  .select($"Value")
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+
|Value|
+-----+
|  XXX|
+-----+
```